# when execute docker-compose up, it throw error said docker-compose up the handshake operation timed out

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, docker-compose

I execute docker-compose up from docker quick start terminal, it throw a ssl error after a while said that

> _ssl.c:574 the handshake operation timed out

[image: the screenshot can be see from here]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. It's caused by the hosts content under windows windows/drivers/etc/hosts, I had added the virtual ip of the docker vm to hosts, after removed the hosts, it work correct.

Comment: what does it mean added ip to hosts? ips are listed there with domain names; what domain name did you use and why? where you do get the vm ip address please? removed after what?